# Is it possible to compile a command line app written in Swift on macOS to run on Linux?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and am writing some simple command line apps. I'm using a Mac.

I know how to compile to a binary that will run on macOS but is it possible to take the same source code and compile the binary to run on Linux from a Mac? If so, any chance it could be compiled to Windows too?

Comment: AFAIK until ABI stability is achieved (which is one of the main goals in Swift 5), it's not possible to compile multi platform binaries in Swift.